# ignore value set by auto form completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've got a little validation plugin that I've written, and I'm setting `data("defaultvalue")` to the value on `document ready`, but it seems there's a wee bug when it comes to auto form completers, they beat me to it.

```
if($(this).val() != ""){
    $(this).data("defaultvalue", $(this).val());
}
```

This is the code I'm using to store the default value, or "placeholder text", and later checking it with:

```
if($(this).data("defaultvalue") && $(this).val() == $(this).data("defaultvalue")) $(this).val("");
```

Any ideas to skip around auto-completion? Or should I just bite the bullet and set the default value data attribute in the markup?

And yes, the only reason I'm not using the `placeholder` attribute, is because of IE. Thank you Microsoft.

Comment: You could give the element a unique name and use `autocomplete="off"` to remove any browser auto complete for modern browsers.

Comment: @MBJ - I don't really want to interfere with a users preferences - if they didn't want autocompletion, they probably wouldn't have turned it on... I think I'm just going to use the data attribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that come across this same problem, I ended up going with setting the data attribute in my markup.

`<input value="Days" data-defaultvalue="Days" />`

It feels a bit like double-handling, but it's the best cross-browser solution to avoid auto-completion scripts.